# Asp.net mvc - change keys before model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have to change the keys (`controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form`) before the binding will happen.

Is this even possible ? I overrided the BindModel method of DefaultModelBinder and tried controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Add() but it's readonly.

I cannot change the form keys in the submited html.

For example

key: xxx_xxx_rownumber_cell

new key: Model[1].Prop1

There are also some dataanotations on the model, so validation should not be omited.

Comment: Can you explain why, and specifically how you are trying to change them?

Comment: Why would you do that? If you want some custom logic to execute when binding, you've got the right place - override methods of DefaultModelBinder

Comment: You really should let us know why you're wanting to do this, there will most likely be a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably found another solution for this some time ago, but if you still want to do it, you should be able to change the form with something like this:

```
var collection = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
PropertyInfo readOnly = collection.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
readOnly.SetValue(collection, false, null);
// Your changes here.
readOnly.SetValue(collection, true, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your action method take the FormCollection as the parameter, and manually bind however you need it to bind?

Also, you could also create a custom model binder for a specific type to utilize this conversion too I believe.

HTH.

Comment: The solution with the FormCollection would skip the model validation and also in the custom model binder the validation would be skipped.